# Can a reactjs component be used in vuejs?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to include a Drag-n-Drop Email Editor in my vuejs project. Unfortunately i can't find one but i did find a really good one for reactjs.  
https://github.com/unlayer/react-email-editor   
Is there a way to use this in my vuejs project?

Comment: both are very different framework of javascript.

Comment: refer https://blog.pragmatists.com/independent-micro-frontends-with-single-spa-library-a829012dc5be